# Are you supposed to run vmware with root, or is there a way around it?

Tags: arch-linux, vmware, privileges

I just installed VMware Workstation Player 17 on Arch Linux. The only way I can get it to run is to run it with sudo in the terminal. Otherwise it goes to the "Welcome to VMware Player" screen where it asks you to enter a license key or use it for free. I select use it for free, but when I hit finish it does nothing. If I run it in the terminal without root, the output after I press finish and put in the password is the fifth line onward:

```
[user@computer ~]$ vmplayer
[AppLoader] Use shipped PC/SC Lite smart card framework.
An up-to-date "pcsc-lite-libs" or "libpcsclite1" package from your system is preferred.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml"
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ====
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-setup-helper' as the super user
Authenticating as: user
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

This is the output if I use sudo:

```
[user@computer ~]$ sudo vmplayer
[sudo] password for user: 
[AppLoader] Use shipped PC/SC Lite smart card framework.
An up-to-date "pcsc-lite-libs" or "libpcsclite1" package from your system is preferred.
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml"
```

Am I supposed to run it this way, or is it an error? It feels dangerous to run it as root so I'd rather not, but I have to run it. If it is an error/bug, how can I fix the issue and run without privileges? Thanks

Comment: I cannot answer your question. I do have Linux machines. Running as root is roughly the same as using Windows with the  normal disabled Administrator. I do not run Windows or Linux this way. I run VMware Workstation Pro V17 in Windows as a normal user

Comment: So it allows you to run it without giving a password?

Comment: You can either run as root, or authenticate using PolicyKit. Have you installed "An up-to-date "pcsc-lite-libs" or "libpcsclite1" package"? Are you running a PolicyKit proxy?

Comment: I have not used Arch so I cannot answer

Comment: I guess that you don't have a polkit agent installed? CF: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit#Authentication_agents

Answer (score 1):

> polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie

Apparently the error is due to a bug in polkit. Somehow the authentication agent registered by `pkexec` cannot authenticate as expected.

A workaround would be have to have a wrapper (also named `pkexec`) in e.g. `/usr/local/bin` (assuming it is in `PATH` and has higher priority than the location of the actual `pkexec`):

```
$ type pkexec
pkexec is /usr/local/bin/pkexec

$ cat /usr/local/bin/pkexec 
#!/bin/sh
pkttyagent & pid=$!
/usr/bin/pkexec "$@"
kill "$pid"

$ pkexec true
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ====
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/true' as the super user
Authenticating as: tom
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====

$ /usr/bin/pkexec true
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ====
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/true' as the super user
Authenticating as: tom
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

Note that `pkttyagent` only works when `pkexec` (or its caller) is run from a terminal. To make things easier, you should probably run a polkit agent with GUI support. The fact that you don't have one running suggests that you are probably using a WM with `startx` instead of a DE. In that case, you will need to install one and start it in `~/.xinitrc`. For example:

```
...
/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 &
exec i3
```